# Using BulkAPI, how to populate multiple objects? (Account, Contact, Opportunity)

Tags: opportunity, account, contact, bulk-api

My company is loading 3rd-party data into SalesForce using the BulkAPI (Python).  This data is loaded into 3 SalesForce objects: Account, Contact, and Opportunity using 'upsert' method with Account External ID based on incoming data.

The problem comes with associating Contact and Opportunity object to Account object.  The API call returns an ID similar to `0016A00000ACjUv` (AccountId), which presumably I should use as unique identifier for Contact and Opportunity (using field name ID).  However, this returns error:

> "INVALID_ID_FIELD:'`0016A00000ACjUv`' is not a valid Salesforce ID for the type Contact"

I've tried number of variations and all of them have fail.

```
job = bulk.create_upsert_job('Contact', 'Id', contentType='CSV', concurrency='Parallel')
```

And

```
job = bulk.create_upsert_job('Contact', 'AccountId', contentType='CSV', concurrency='Parallel')
```

Has anyone experienced this and what solution would you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

Any ID starting with the [001 keyprefix](http://www.fishofprey.com/2011/09/obscure-salesforce-object-key-prefixes.html#001) is for Account.

The error message:

> "INVALID_ID_FIELD:'0016A00000ACjUv' is not a valid Salesforce ID for the type Contact"

Suggests the code is trying to use the ID of an Account as the ID for a Contact.

I suspect you have put the Account ID into the wrong field on the Contact record. That value should go into the `Contact.AccountID` field to relate it back to the parent Account.

See also:

- [Relationship Fields in a Header Row](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/datafiles_csv_rel_field_header_row.htm)